# Get corresponding Id for the MAX() record in a group

Tags: soql

I have a custom Object that has a `End__c` field.

I am trying to get the MAX() record for each of the owners given a date condition.

I have a query written like so:

```
SELECT  
     MAX(Id) id, 
     OwnerId, 
     MAX(End__c) end 
     FROM My_Object__c where OwnerId IN :userIds 
     AND End__c != NULL AND End__c >= :startOfDay 
     GROUP BY OwnerId
```

The problem is that `Max(Id)` does not actually correspond to the record from which `MAX(End__c)` is pulled.

How can i get a result like so:

```
OwnerId | Max(End__c) | Id
```

**Update**

Note: to repro this you need data created concurrently such that the Ids are not sequential in the custom sObject in relation to values in our custom field, e.g. here we run full query (`select Id, End__c, CreatedDate From My_Object__c WHERE OwnerId = 'XX'`)

[image: First query]

And here we can see that same query but with filter by Id (`select Id, End__c, CreatedDate From My_Object__c WHERE OwnerId = 'XX' AND Id > '...GuuEAG'`), you can see that records are not sorted in the order of our custom `End__c`

[image: Second query]

Comment: I ran a similar query on Account object using the CreatedDate field (instead of End__c) and I was able to get correct result. However, if there are many records with the same created date, then the ID corresponds to the most recently created record. Have you checked there are no duplicate records with same End__c value??

Comment: @arut When i run this even having 3 records where `End__c` is say `2020-03-23T02:23:00Z`, `2020-03-23T04:31:00Z`, `2020-03-23T11:12:23Z` and the `startOfDay` is `2020-03-22T14:00:00Z` i get the Id from one, and the End__c from another.

Comment: I thought this may be due to the custom date field being not indexed, but that doesn't seem to be the case either. I created a custom datetime field, updated it with all distinct dates and the query is still giving me correct result. Let me know if you find the root cause.

Comment: @arut see above, i think you are doing this sequentially, such that if sorted by `Id` you will get same sort as by `End__c`. But for us `End__c` does not necessarily correspond with `Id` at all, meaning sorting or `MAX()` on `Id` gives us different results from sorting or `MAX` on `End__c`

Comment: I think you are correct. All the records in my query results were non-sequential, but for the top most record (i.e., while sorting by Id vs Datetime field, the top most record was the same and the other records were non-sequential). This is same as the sequential scenario you have mentioned. Now, I'm able to replicate the problem.

Comment: I doubt this can be done in a single SOQL query. Writing apex code could be the only possible solution.

Comment: @arut I am moving along with that approach, too, but I was hoping that maybe there is some magic that somebody knows :/